# Is there an online list of twilio media resources

Tags: twilio

Is it possible to get a list of media resources for my account online without writing code.  I have stumbled around and failed to find the list.  Surely there must be a way.

Comment: "Without writing code" will make this post off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions need to be about programming. This seems like a question best directed to Twilio's support team.

Comment: Also, not clear what you mean by media resources. Twilio has a CLI you could possibly use, https://www.twilio.com/docs/twilio-cli/quickstart, and often code samples for different languages also have syntax for doing same via the Twilio CLI.